# Items added to subview are not displayed incrementally

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have a thread that is adding UIView elements to another parent UIView.  I'm trying to add these one every second, however they are not displayed until the entire loop is completed.  See the code below.

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    NSThread *thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(addSubViews) object:nil];
    [thread start];
}

-(void)addSubViews {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i, 0, 10, 10)];
        [parentView addSubview:view];
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
    }
}
```

I would expect to see these views added one at a time, every 1 seconds.  However nothing shows up on the parent view until the entire loop completes.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gack. Forget you ever knew about sleep. Really.

You can't do UI code from a background thread.

Changes to your app's UI don't take effect until the next pass through the event loop. You need to return and let the system process your code. Something more like this:

The header:

```
@interface MyVC: UIViewController
{
  int viewIndex;
}
```

The body:

```
#define K_MAX_VIEWS 10

@implementation MyVC

-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender 
{
  viewIndex = 0;
  [self addViews];
}

- (void) addViews;
{
  if (viewIndex < K_MAX_VIEWS)
  {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*15, 0, 10, 10)];
    [parentView addSubview:view];
    view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0 //Testing: Box the view so you can see it.
    viewIndex++;
    [self performSelector: @selector(addViews) withObject: nil afterDelay: 1];
  }
}
@end
```

This code uses an instance variable to keep track of the index of the view it's adding. It adds a view, then returns, after making a call to `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`. This method schedules a future call on the main thread after a delay. That's how you want to handle this.

Note that you likely won't see **anything** as a result of this code unless you make the view that you're adding display something in the view. Thats why I added the line `view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

UIKit is not thread safe, so all calls to it must be made on the main thread.  Try this:

```
-(void)addSubViews {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        dispatch_sync( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i, 0, 10, 10)];
            [parentView addSubview:view];
        } );
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use NSThread, use GCD. For example:

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    [self addSubViews];
}

-(void)addSubViews {

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i, 0, 10, 10)];
      [parentView addSubview:view];
      [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];
    });

  }
}
```

Explanation: you put 10 asynchronous tasks to add a subview and wait for 1 second to the main queue.